# how to do camera for taking snap and stored into SD card?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-camera

I need to know initially how camera starts and if button press snap and store into SD card. How to store to SD card?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We expect you to have attempted to solve this problem by yourself rather than asking the community to arrive at a complete solution for you. When you've got some code to show us that demonstrates some effort by you (even if it's wrong) please update your question and flag to re-open. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lot of samples available for Camera app. Try this:

```
    preview = new Preview(this);
    ((FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.preview)).addView(preview);

    buttonClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonClick);
    buttonClick.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            preview.camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);
        }
    });
```

Take the full source code from [here](http://www.ziddu.com/download/17491650/CameraDemo.zip.html).

Answer (score 1):

You need to check out the camera API. Here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html

Tie your button to the relevant function, it's pretty well described there.